# Cannot send a string longer than 1333 characters by POST without the page timing out

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have a problem sending an input hidden field containing more that 1333 characters. If the string contains more than 1333 characters, then when I try to send the form via POST, the page times out. Is there a setting anywhere that I have to change ?

I'm using Symfony2, I don't know if there is something related to that ? Strangely, it does work on my web server, but not on my local computer.

Here's the form:

```
<form  action="{{ path('osc_dashboard_playerEvaluation_evaluationSession_evaluate', {"evaluationSessionId" : evaluationSession.id}) }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <!-- This will be generated with Twig so it is normal that is does not correspond to the data below -->
            <tr>
                <th style="width:50px;">Nom</th>
                {% for test in tests %}
                    <th colspan="{{ test[1] }}" style="text-align:center;">{{ test[0] }}</th>
                {% endfor %}

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                {% for test in tests %}
                    {% for testNumber in 1..test[1] %}
                        <th style="width:30px;text-align: center;">{{ testNumber }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: playersEvaluation()">
            <tr data-bind="">
                <td data-bind="text: $data.playerName"></td>
                <!-- ko foreach: evaluatedExercises -->
                <!-- ko foreach:tries -->
                <td style="width:30px;text-align:center;">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: result" style="text-align:center;width:30px;" />
                </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>



        <input type="hidden" id="results" name="results" data-bind="value: exportToJSON() " />

        <input type="hidden" name="resultsJSON" id="resultsJSON" value="{{ resultsJSON }}" />
        <br />
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <button class="btn btn-success">Sauvegarder</button>
        <a class="btn" href="{{ path('osc_dashboard_playerEvaluation_evaluationSession') }}">Annuler les modifications</a>
    </form>
```

Also, both servers have the same files since they all take their data from a git repo.

**Here's my local configuration:**

```
Symfony2 version: 2.2.3
MAC OSX 10.8.4
MAMP Pro
PHP version: 5.4.4
```

**Here's my server configuration:**

```
Symfony2 version: 2.2.3
Ubuntu 12.04
PHP version: PHP 5.4.15-1~precise+1
```

**Here's what I tried to do to get a clue on why the data is not sent on my local computer.**

- I deleted Symfony2 dev.log, clicked on the button to send the form, got the time out error and unfortunately, the log is still empty....
- Also, all the php and apache logs do not show anything...
- I've set post_max_size = 500M
- I've set LimitBodyRequest 0

You can see my phpinfo page here: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/VZfeQ/

I have really no clue on why this particular data won't get send...

I found that this was the problem coming a long way from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601461/sending-a-form-containing-a-serialized-json-object-causes-a-timeout

**Update 2**

I changed the execution time and after 4 minutes, I got a Symfony error: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/Em4Fp/

Answer (score 0):

This has probably to do with either:

the value of [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in the php configuration (measured in bytes with an optional K, M, and G Suffixes)

or

the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive of apache (measured in bytes).

Comment: It is not the post_max_size, 500M, I'm pretty sure two input text fields of a couple of characters and one of 1333 characters would burst 500M. Also, at 1333, the page loads really quick without any delay. I'll look for LimitRequestBody, is it in httpd.conf ?

Comment: there virtual host config or .htaccess