# Cannot send a string of more than 1333 characters

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have a strange problem. I cannot send a form if one the fields has a string of more than 1333 characters.

Here's my simple html page:

```
<form method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="a" value="WffapzB...truncated" />

<input type="submit" value="OK" />

</form>
```

The problem comes from Apache or my Computer since when I load the html file in the browser (file://localhost/Users/etienne/Developpement/htdocs/test/SendForm/index.html), without passing through the server, the form gets sent.

If I access it via the server (http://tests.localhost/SendForm/), the page times out.

Here's what I have tried:

- Also, all the php and apache logs do not show anything...
- I've set post_max_size = 500M
- I've set LimitBodyRequest 0

You can see my phpinfo page here: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/VZfeQ/

What can cause a page not to accept strings longer than 1333 characters on server side ? Clearly, it is not a browser problem since it doesn't work on other browsers and it works using the html file. Therefore, the problem comes when the server is in the process.

**Update 2**

I completely removed MAMP Server and reinstalled the Mac OS X native server without success. Therefore, it is not linked with MAMP PRO but with other things that I have not clue about...

**Update 3**

I also found out that the same problem occurs sending the data via GET.

**Update 4**

Using wireshark on my local adapter, I see no POST data being sent. I see the http requests for that page but it doesn't show any POST requests. If I launch another site, then I will see the POST requests for that site. : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2quoUxT9OnJdmN3ajJVR2dPbUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Isn't this the same as your last question?

Comment: No, since now I know Symfony has nothing to do with that...

Comment: is that darn Suhosin stuff enabled?

Comment: Did you try that post with your native apache2 server to confirm if it's your confirmation and not a generic apache/php limit?

Comment: no, Suhosin is no enable. I'm currently testing using mac osx apache2 native server and will return.

Comment: @ToBe I tested using mac osx apache2 native server and it still doesn't work !!!!!! After 2 hours or reconfiguring everything, the same bug...

Comment: Have you checked your webservice's error log?

Comment: @PeeHaa do you mean apache error log ?

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes, I looked at the apache error log and there's nothing...

Comment: Are you sure it's "POST"ed and not somwhere redirected to GET ?

Comment: @ToBe I think so, google chrome shows it's posted: http://i.imgur.com/K8IVYN6.png

Comment: Might be worth checking that the package shown in your Chrome debugger is not already truncated.

Comment: @ToBe It doesn't seem like the package is truncated: http://imgur.com/SNx6qSB

Comment: I cant reproduce that problem with xampp (php 5.3, Apache2). Can you post the complete HTML code or strip all but the shown above (with a proper "action") ?

Comment: If you cant see anything posted, your wireshark is most probably not listening. You get data (even if not enough) and it should appear there.

Did you check this one?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621394/cannot-send-a-string-longer-than-1333-characters-by-post-without-the-page-timing?rq=1

Comment: @ToBe That's all I have in my file, only the html code posted... Concerning Wireshark, I'm listening but no POST data are sent. I can see the http requests, but there is no POST data sent.

Comment: Are you sure there is no action attribute in your form tag?

Comment: @ToBe no there is none.

Comment: A form without action will send towards the same url. Is that correct in your case?

Comment: @ToBe yes, because I only wanted to see if at the least the page would get refreshed, which would normally do since I don't the post data. And even that doesn't work, I still get a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it ! After hours and days of searching, I decided to reactivate the firewall. Then, I got a request from a program called HideMyIp (that I completely forgot that I had installed). I deleted that program, restarted my computer, and everything was then working fine ! Thanks to everyone that have tried to help me !

Comment: It's allways the least obvious things :)